# Semantic UI - ui grid best approach for layout (rows/columns vs segments)

Tags: grid, semantic-ui

I'm new to **Semantic UI** and I'm trying to design a webpage with the layout below. Looking at the documentation, I've decided to use `ui page grid`. I've also decided to define the top fixed menu outside of the grid.

[image]

My first approach was something like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="ui page grid">
        <div class="three column row">
            <div class="column"> Horizontal section, column 1</div>
            <div class="column"> Horizontal section, column 2</div>
            <div class="column"> Horizontal section, column 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="two column row">
            <div class="column"> 
                <div class="row"> Left column, row 1</div>
                <div class="row"> Left column, row 2</div>
                <div class="row"> Left column, row 3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="row"> Right column, row 1</div>
                <div class="row"> Right column, row 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My question is:

Is it the correct approach to achieve a layout similar to the one of the image ? Should I use `segments` to divide the content instead of rows or columns ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 20):

Semantic UI wanted `segments` to mean parts of text/articles. They [left a small note](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/segment.html#horizontal-segment):

> A segment is used to create a grouping of related content. Horizontal
>   segments are most effectively used with grids, to allow for text
>   groups that are aligned across grid rows.

In essence, they mean that `grid` is the foundation of your markup. The `grid` has been designed for laying out the page.

You can use `segments` within your grid to group similar content. (If you look more in the docs, you can see that intention where they have `stacked`, `piled`, `loading` classes for `segments`.)

For example, I'd like to have the three cells in the bottom left as some sort of news feed. Then I'd use segments there:

```
<body>
    <div class="ui page grid">
        <div class="three column row">
            <div class="column"> Horizontal section, column 1</div>
            <div class="column"> Horizontal section, column 2</div>
            <div class="column"> Horizontal section, column 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="two column row">
            <div class="column"> 
                <div class="ui segment">
                    <div class="ui vertical segment">
                        <p>Left column, row 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui vertical segment">
                        <p>Left column, row 2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui vertical segment">
                        <p>Left column, row 3</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="row"> Right column, row 1</div>
                <div class="row"> Right column, row 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[image: Grid with segments]

Comment: Got it ! That means that any content that is not text should not be grouped using `segment`. I initially used it because i needed to divide the left cells with an horizontal divider and `segment` automatically adds it between the different content. Then, the most correct approach for achieving something like that would be using `columns` and `rows` and `ui dividers` between, right ?

Comment: ah! that's dicey. :P TLDR: yes.

I just had a look at the `divider` class docs, where they mentioned that vertical and horizontal dividers can be used to segment content. (overlap of words, don't you think? ;-))

but i'd assume they mean to divide unrelated content here. :-) hope this helps!~

small note: `segments` can be used for (related) things other than text as well. like a list of thumbnail images for a product on a shop page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `stretched grid` to stretching the segments vertically, so they would have the same height. And use the `.ui.segments` could help you to keep the code clean. [[*Online Demo*]](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pLavPQ)

[image]

CSS

```
.segment {
   min-height: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="ui horizontal segments">
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
    <div class="segment"></div>
</div>
<div class="ui stretched two column grid">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="ui vertical segments">
            <div class="segment"></div>
            <div class="segment"></div>
            <div class="segment"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="ui segment"></div>
        <div class="ui segment"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```